# Docker OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused

Tags: linux, docker

I have been working on a project for almost a year, and this project has been working in Docker. Today I noticed that the permissions of the entire file system changed to 777 (all files "-rwxrwxrwx"). I don’t know why all this happened and I wanted to fix it.

I ran two Bash command:

```
find ./ -type -d exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./ -type -f exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After that I wanted to see the result and I run this command `ls -l` and I saw such a message `Permission denied`, the worst thing that could happen. I could not run a single command, and decided to get out of the container. After that the nightmare began. And now when I try to start the container again I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Error: failed to start containers:
```

I do not want to think about the worst, because I can’t afford to lose this container, I really need it. My OS Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What docker version do you have?

Comment: Perhaps you removed exec permission (`x`) on `bash` or any other binary in `/usr/local/bin` or wherever it's located.

Comment: @dejdej 19.03.8

Comment: @StefanGolubović but have some ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to run a command in a stopped container from host?

Comment: Not really,   if you do a`$docker ps -a ` check the container name, and then `$docker start -ai CONTAINER` , you have the same error ?

Comment: @K-sS-k how did you try to `exec` into container?

Comment: `docker exec`  command runs a new command in a running container (`docker ps` shows running containers) and `docker start` it is to start a stopped container (`docker ps -a` shows stopped containers).  If your container is running you can try `docker exec -itu 0 container_name /bin/sh` or `docker exec -itu 0 container_name /bin/bash` depending on which shell do you have in the container.

Comment: My guess would be that your container data is safe, unless you used the `--rm` flag on `docker run`. You just have to reset the permissions of your files inside the container back to make them runnable. I agree with @dejdej - trying `docker ps --all` is a good next step. Can you see your (stopped) container in this list?

Comment: @halfer I see my container when trying `docker ps -a`

Comment: But it `docker start my_container` gives an error

Comment: I think all of from this `executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: I would be inclined to try running a `chmod` command using `docker commit --change 'RUN find ./ -type -d exec chmod 777 {} \;'` ([see here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)). However you should at least back up your containers before doing so, and maybe wait for other folks in here to advise on that too.

Comment: (As I understand it, `docker commit` takes a container file system and runs a new command on top of it, creating a new version of the file system. I think that might be enough to make the container startable. However, as I say, backups are key here).

Comment: Now I geting this error `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": permission denied": unknown.`

Comment: Please pull the image latest and container to up date  will works for me.

Answer (score 31):

Adding "bash" in the Entrypoint worked for me:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash","entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Comment: This exact line helped me. I had error with `mysqld` and `redis-server`. And yes this line should get added to `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Does not work on Fedora 34

Comment: don’t use `bash` in any case, better just take the shell command from the entrypoint script’s shebang, i.e. the output of: `grep -om1 '[^/]*$' docker-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: I am having the same issue but "bash" didn't help I have a shebang ie in docker-entrypoint.sh #!/bin/bash, Furthermore, I have <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <entrypoint>/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh</entrypoint> .....still having error  Warning  Failed     7m55s (x3 over 8m10s)  kubelet            Error: failed to start container "app": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh":

Comment: stat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

Answer (score 5):

First check the service status:

```sh
systemctl status docker
```

Try a restart:

```sh
systemctl restart docker
```

I had the same issue and the solution for me it was to update the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` (`systemctl edit docker.service`) more exactly  I deleted the `MountFlags=slave` from the unit file and afterwards `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already checked it, and there is no  MountFlags=slave

Comment: yes the complete docker application restart resolved my issue....

Answer (score 3):

In my case, to resolve the error message, I also had to enable the integration between Docker Desktop for Windows and the Ubuntu distro running on WSL2. I installed the distro *after* Docker Desktop and forgot about this step.

[image]

Comment: Yup, this worked for me but I had to turn it on for ALL my distros for some reason just enabling it for the one I was using wasn't enough. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after a `dnf update` on Fedora 34 which included a Docker update.

Downgrading `containerd.io` worked for me.

```
sudo dnf downgrade containerd.io
```

Comment: dnf downgrade containerd.io
Last metadata expiration check: 3:52:00 ago on Fri Oct 22 14:55:43 2021.
Packages for argument containerd.io available, but not installed.
Error: No packages marked for downgrade.