# Having trouble with installing Docker on Window's Ubuntu WSL

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm in the middle of installing Docker on Windows' Ubuntu WSL but having trouble. Here's the installation guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

The specific error I'm getting when I try to run the command at the end (`sudo docker run hello-world`) is: `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.`

I went through all the steps but didn't get any errors until the end and got that error, but I don't think step 2 was done properly. Is this command supposed to output anything?

`echo \ "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`

If so, what should it output? I'm asking since I see the `echo` command. Or is it just piping that output to the second command? What's the best way to see which step succeeded or failed in this installation process? I'm not familiar enough to triage what's going wrong

Comment: You may need to install from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

Answer (score 3):

You are installing Docker Engine directly on Ubuntu WSL, which is fine, but I want to be sure you understand that you have another option.  The "recommended" method is to install [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows).

Docker Desktop does provide a few additional features over the base Docker Engine:

- It can be shared amongst multiple WSL2 instances
- It can run from PowerShell and CMD
- It provides a GUI dashboard of containers and volumes
- It handles automatic upgrades (although some might not consider that necessarily an advantage)
- It's a convenience method that handles all of the other stuff below automatically for you.

Both versions run the same engine underneath, but Desktop just provides those additional convenience features as well.  If you don't need or want these, and you really do want to just install Docker Engine, then the solution to your current issue should be to just run:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Then try the sample again.  It's an extra step that's required in WSL that isn't covered in the Docker doc.

(Bonus tip) I recommend running `hello-world` via:

```
sudo docker run --rm hello-world
```

There's no reason to leave that particular container hanging around after it exits, IMHO.  I wish Docker would update those docs.

Also, assuming everything works at that point, I recommend getting rid of that image via:

```
sudo docker rmi hello-world
```

*Explanation:*

On "regular" Ubuntu, part of the installation process performed by the `docker-ce` package is to start the Docker daemon.  However, that step fails due to differences in the way WSL works (lack of runlevels, systemd, startup script support, etc).

So when you get to that (currently) Step 3 to verify that the daemon is running via `docker run ...`, it's not.

You're also going to run into a similar issue when you get to the section "Post-installation steps for Linux:  Configure Docker to start on boot"*

This won't work on WSL, since there's no concept of a "boot" (and, again, no Systemd).  So you'll need an alternate method to make sure the engine is running in WSL.  That can, of course, simply be a manual `sudo service docker start` when you need it.  Or you can, if you'd like, add something like the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start"
```

There are other methods as well, but that's just one example.

As for the lack of any output when adding the repository key, that's expected since the output (Stdout) is piped to `/dev/null`.  If there was an error, it would likely still be reported on Stderr.

Comment: Got it working! So I had to configure Docker Desktop as well, since that was already installed from earlier this year. Basically, what I had to do was update the Ubuntu to WSL 2 following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 . Then I integrated Docker with the distro like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64941038/1175788 and then I followed your steps

Comment: However, I am getting this error when I try to spin down the hello-world: `Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "hello-world" (must force) - container be74db2e9bba is using its referenced image d1165f221234`